# Oracle Access Manager error : No message for The Access Server has returned a status that is unknown to the AccessGate

Tags: java, oracle-access-manager

One Java enterprise application  (EAR with EJB) in Staging environment is giving me an OAM error when I click a link on the page. The link is nothing but a page number. Page number 1 works fine but when I click the link of page number 2 or any other page or click first/previous/next/last link it gives following error:

Oracle Access Manager Operation Error
No message for The Access Server has returned a status that is unknown to the AccessGate .

Contact your website administrator to remedy this problem.

However, the same functionality is working in the Integration (Development) environment application. Both the environments run on Weblogic 12c on separate 
Unix servers. Also a single access team has configured the IAM Authentication of them using OAM (Oracle Access Manager). They have used separate hosts for 
access servers for these environments.

Below are the respective URLs for the page on Integration and Staging (I have modified the labels as I cannot reveal the actual URLs )

Integration: http://intApp1-int.na.orgName.net/appName/pageName.do?d-1234567-p=2&flagPage=<%&listRecords=SelectedValue%7C%7C0&isAnotherFlag=Yes&xyz1=U

Staging: http://stagingApp-qa.na.orgName.net/appName/pageName.do?d-1234567-p=2&flagPage=<%&listRecords=SelectedValue%7C%7C0&isAnotherFlag=Yes&xyz1=U

What the access team is saying that the issue is with the URL and the first % character needs to be followed by a number like below:

http://stagingApp-qa.na.orgName.net/appName/pageName.do?d-1234567-p=2&flagPage=<**%25**&listRecords=SelectedValue%7C%7C0&isAnotherFlag=Yes&xyz1=U

Their workaround is working , also the Oracle site is also saying the same:[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e14771/oam.htm](http://Oracle%20Docs) . But user cannot always modify the URL each time he hits a new page. Also , to our surprise the Integration URL is working without any number after first %.

Please help to figure out what could be the root cause of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using characters instead of encoded form e.g %7C in the url

Comment: Thanks @Tahseen , yes this can be achieved. But my question is why OAM is behaving differently for the 2 environments? What could be the root cause behind this?

Comment: You can check if WebService  acting differently in two environments. You can check if system skips any component of OAM architecture e.g AccessGate in integration environment.

Comment: Thanks @Tahseen , but the OAM part is managed by a different team. They are saying the configuration is same in both environments. I wanted to know what part of OAM is responsible for URL encoding, so that I can guide them.

Comment: Browser automatically should encode the url, but here you are sending it in encoded form. In simple scenario, Client application sends the request to AccessGate and AccessGate process the request and sends it to webservice. There the decoding happens and resource is sent back. I think in stage environment during decoding, it is expecting something after the % so that it can be decoded, but it is missing the required information after the %, so the decoding is not happening and the proper resource can not be found.